Chromedriver is not working in some of my clients laptop. but it work for many
I have a bot written in selenium and wraped up in electron js, in somesystem it works fine but in somesystem it fails to run, i try to dignose and cometo know that in some system it failed to download the chromedriver, please help me..!!
yes i tried to do many things but failed.

you'd need to include some specific exceptions thrown on those machines.  If it's always a download failure, just include the driver executable(s) and extract during installation or run-time.
